# Check if element in list string BigQuery

Tags: arrays, string, split, google-bigquery

I have a comma separated list in BigQuery

```
select '1,2,3' as number_list
```

I want to return true if 1 is in the list without splitting into an array then unnesting

I want to be able to say

```
select if(1 in split('1,2,3'),1,0)
```

I also want to avoid saying

```
select if('1,2,3' like '%,1,%' or '1,2,3' like '1,%' or '1,2,3' like '%,1',1,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION InList(list STRING, num INT64) AS ((
  SELECT COUNTIF(num = CAST(number AS INT64)) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(list)) number
));
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1,2,3' AS number_list UNION ALL
  SELECT '2,3,4'
)
SELECT number_list, InList(number_list, 1) in_list
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row number_list in_list  
1   1,2,3       1    
2   2,3,4       0
```

> I also want to avoid saying
>       `SELECT IF('1,2,3' LIKE '%,1,%' OR '1,2,3' LIKE '1,%' OR '1,2,3' LIKE '%,1',1,0)`

to avoid such redundancy you can use below version

```
SELECT IF(CONCAT(',', number_list, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,1,%'), 1, 0)
```

... And, finally - and most likely the winner :o)

> I want to be able to say `select if(1 in split('1,2,3'),1,0)`

The closest is

```
SELECT IF('1' IN UNNEST(SPLIT(number_list)), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use subquery with MAX function matching your searched value

```
SELECT  id, 
(SELECT MAX(IF(n = 1, n, null)) = 1 FROM  UNNEST(number_list) AS  n)
FROM (
SELECT
1 AS id,
[1,2,3] AS number_list
)
```

or with

```
SELECT  id, 
(SELECT MAX(IF(n = '1', n, null)) = '1' FROM  UNNEST(number_list) AS  n)

FROM (
SELECT
1 AS id,
SPLIT('1,2,3',',') AS number_list
)
```